# How to create Custom View in React-Big-Calender?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, react-big-calendar

i am trying to create custom Agenda view, but i am getting error **'View.title is not a function'**. I referred to documentation example and this github issue also (https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/issues/1544#issuecomment-699951170), but still no success. 
I came across this codeSandox where Year view was implemented (https://codesandbox.io/s/jjmky5047y), i tried to do the same but still having the same error. Please help 
Link to my codeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-big-calendar-custom-year-view-forked-ji8sc?file=/src/index.js

Comment: _Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**_. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). A CodeSandbox is nice as a demo but it cannot be the only place the code exists. The question must be complete within itself too.

Answer (score 1):

Custom 'views', in React-Big-Calendar, require two static methods, `navigate`, and `title`, as well as an optional third method for `range`.

The `navigate` method allow custom navigation applied to your view

```js
Agenda.navigate = (
  date,
  action,
  { length = Agenda.defaultProps.length, localizer }
) => {
  switch (action) {
    case navigate.PREVIOUS:
      return localizer.add(date, -length, 'day')

    case navigate.NEXT:
      return localizer.add(date, length, 'day')

    default:
      return date
  }
}
```

And the `title` method is used to localize your view title.

```js
Agenda.title = (start, { length = Agenda.defaultProps.length, localizer }) => {
  let end = localizer.add(start, length, 'day')
  return localizer.format({ start, end }, 'agendaHeaderFormat')
}
```

The `range` method returns the `start` and `end` dates of your view. This is required if you expect `onRangeChange` to be called from your custom view during navigation.

```js
Agenda.range = (start, { length = Agenda.defaultProps.length, localizer }) => {
  let end = localizer.add(start, length, 'day')
  return { start, end }
}
```

This pattern is outlined in the [documentation](http://jquense.github.io/react-big-calendar/examples/index.html#prop-views) for the 'views' prop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CustomToolbar = (toolbar) => {
        const goToBack = () => {
          toolbar.onNavigate('PREV');
        };
        const goToNext = () => {
          toolbar.onNavigate('NEXT');
        };
        const goToCurrent = () => {
          toolbar.onNavigate('TODAY');
        };
        const date = moment(toolbar.date);
        const year = date.format('YYYY');
        const label = toolbar.label.match(/\D/g).join('');
    
        return (
          <div className="rbc-toolbar">
            <span className="rbc-btn-group">
              <span className="rbc-btn-group">
                <button type="button" onClick={goToCurrent}>
                  <span className="next-icon">Today</span>
                </button>
                <button type="button" onClick={goToBack}>
                  <span className=" fa fa-chevron-left" />
                </button>
                <button type="button" onClick={goToNext}>
                  <span className=" fa fa-chevron-right" />
                </button>
              </span>
            </span>
            <span className="rbc-toolbar-label">
              {label} {year}
            </span>
            <span className="rbc-btn-group" />
          </div>
        );
      };
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).